# meterGaugeChart does not show

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I followed the [meterGaugeChart example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/meterGaugeChart.jsf) and it doesn't show in JSP.

When I view the source in browser I found

```
<p:meterGaugeChart value="org.primefaces.model.chart.MeterGaugeChartModel@1818f80"></p:meterGaugeChart>
```

I'm using `primefaces-3.0.jar`, `jsf-api-2.0.3.jar`, `jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar`, `jstl-1.0.2.jar`.

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="template/commonLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
                <p:meterGaugeChart value="#{welcome.meterGaugeModel}" /> 
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, PrimeFaces 2.x/3.x does not support JSP. It works in Facelets only. But since you are using Facelets tags in your code example and you didn't seem to complain that Facelets tags are also visible in the HTML source, I assume that you're just confusing JSP with Facelets. Facelets is XHTML based and the successor of the old and deprecated JSP. If your file extension is `.xhtml`, then you're all set. But if it is *really* `.jsp`, then you need to rename it to `.xhtml`.

Second of all, you're using there a completely outdated JSTL version. You need JSTL 1.2 which you can [download](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) as `jstl-1.2.jar`. Replace the `jstl-1.0.3.jar` altogether (and make sure that you don't have a `standard.jar` file).

Finally, you need to make sure that you've declared the proper PrimeFaces 3.0 namespace in the root tag of the Facelet XHTML file. It should point to `http://primefaces.org/ui`.

```
<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```